# ¿Como ocultar sidenav?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, materialize

Me encuentro con un proyecto con `HTML`, `CSS` y `JavaScript`, estoy utilizando la librería de `materialize`, y quiero ocultar el `sidenav` en el momento en que llamo a una función o en la propia función de cerrar sesión del usuario. Mi código en `JavaScript` es el siguiente:

```
mostrarNav:function(nickAlumno){
  $('#logoSide').remove();
  var cadena= '<li id="inicio_d"><a href="#" onclick="app.pantallaAlumno();">Inicio</a></li><li id="resultados_d"><a href="#">Resultados</a></li><li id="cerrar_d"><a href="#" onclick="app.cerrarSesion();">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>';
  var cadena2= '<a href="#" id="logoSide" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="mobile-nav"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>';
  var cadena3='<li><div class="user-view"><div class="background"><img src="cliente-apache/img/pizarra-800x478.jpg"></div><a href="#user"><img src="cliente-apache/img/user.png" style="width:20%"></a><span class="white-text name">'+nickAlumno+'</span></div></li>';
  cadena3= cadena3+'<li ><a href="#" onclick="app.pantallaAlumno();">Inicio</a></li><li ><a href="#">Resultados</a></li><li><div class="divider"></div></li><li ><a href="#" onclick="app.cerrarSesion();">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>';
  $('#navBar').append(cadena);
  $('#navSide').append(cadena2);
  $('#mobile-nav').append(cadena3);

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  });
},

cerrarSesion:function(){
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('alu')!=undefined){
    window.localStorage.removeItem("alu");
    app.formLogin();  

  }
},
```

En esta parte estaría el `sidenav` y la función donde me gustaría que se ocultara (cerrar Sesión). He probado a hacer un `remove`, pero a la hora de volver a iniciar sesión me sobrescribe el contenido. El código en `HTML` es este:

```
<nav class="blue" style="padding: 0px 10px;">
    <div class="nav-wrapper" id="navSide">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">EDUCA</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down" id="navBar"></ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-nav"></ul>
```

Comment: Cuando se ejecuta la función? un onClick, al iniciar el documento?

Comment: Si, se trata de un onClick que se encuentra en el propio sidenav. Es decir, una de las filas del sidenav es cerrarSesion, por tanto al darle se debe salir de la sesión y ocultar

Answer (score 2):

Saludos puedes usar algo de javascript:

```
cerrarSesion:function(){
  //ocultar sidenav
  sideNav = document.getElementById('mobile-nav');
  sideNav.style.display = 'none';
  ...
  ..

},
```

Si prefieres usa Jquery:

```
$("#mobile-nav").hide();
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por comentar. He probado a hacerlo, y el problema es que al salir me lo oculta, pero al volver a entrar sigue estando oculto. ¿Existe la función contraria al hide?

Comment: en efecto para ello si usas Jquery... colocal "$("#ID).show();"

Comment: Vale, he probado justo eso. Y lo hace bien. Pero hay otro problema, pues al volver a entrar lo que sucede es que me duplica lo que tenía en el sidenav. Es decir, si tengo (inicio, resultados y cerrar sesión), me lo vuelve a poner abajo repetido

Comment: Ya está solucionado, he añadido un id a cada una de las etiquetas <li> del sidenav, y en la función mostrarNav, al comienzo hago $("#ID).remove(); Muchas gracias por la ayuda.